# Google Sheet Query and locale decimal numbers

Tags: google-sheets, locale, number-formatting, google-query-language

I'm using Query function in Google Sheets but even if my files are set to locale Italy when I want to filters records with value that have numbers with decimal (commas not dot) example 10,45 the query return me error.

Example:

QUERY(A1:B3;"Select count(A) where B>" & B6 & " label count(A) ''")

where A1:B3 is a simple example table like:

Stefano 50,00
Fabio   42,00
Andrea  50,00

And B6 is a cell where you put the value you want. Example if I type 48 the query return me 2.
But if you put value with decimals, example 48,3, an error is returned.
Seems that locale in the properties of sheet is not recognized by Query command.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fM5dmtJ8ih9ZqHnC1VMw3Azepvrwn0HYfJN49RF1d0k/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: answer updated...

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=QUERY(A1:B3;
 "select count(A) 
  where B > "&SUBSTITUTE(B8; ","; ".")&" 
  label count(A) ''")
```

[image]

---

or shorter:

```
=QUERY(A1:B3;
 "select count(A) 
  where B > "&TEXT(B8; "#,#")&" 
  label count(A) ''")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi player0, thanks with SUBSTITUTE command all works but the BIG question is: why I need to use this command as workaround? The "locale" inside Google Sheets "should" solve everything about how numbers with decimal are displayed between different countries. Seems that Query command don't recognize the locale.

Comment: @user1297545 QUERY does not account for locale at all. its SQL based